# How to get first day of current month in php?

Tags: php

What I want to do is get 1st date of current month

**Here is how to get last day of the current month**

```
date('d-m-Y', strtotime('last day of this month'))
```

**I've tried to use this, but it didn't work for me**

```
date('d-m-Y', strtotime('first day of this month'))
```

Any idea how to solve my problem ?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094797/the-first-day-of-the-current-month-in-php-using-date-modify-as-datetime-object

Comment: mktime would also work here.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

`date('01-m-Y')` should do it ;)

Answer (score 10):

```
date('d-m-Y', strtotime(date('Y-m-1')));
```

Comment: Ew, converting a format to a date string to a number to another date string... This is almost as bad as the people who do `$("#"+$(this).attr('id'))` in jQuery...

Comment: @Kolink: I'm sure the outer `date()` is used just to prove the result is correct, while the timestamp is the desired result

Comment: Is this really that bad? Seems to work well if you used a date format variable (or constant) and have the need to do something like this. Then if you change your date format, you won't have to also change things like this. `$dateFormat = "d F, Y"; echo date($dateFormat, strtotime(date('Y-m-1')));`

Comment: Any solution using `strtotime()` is bad because that function gives the caller a lot of freedom and does a lot of guesswork to figure out what they were trying to say, and so is very slow

Answer (score 10):

```
$firstDayUTS = mktime (0, 0, 0, date("m"), 1, date("Y"));
$lastDayUTS = mktime (0, 0, 0, date("m"), date('t'), date("Y"));

$firstDay = date("d-m-Y", $firstDayUTS);
$lastDay = date("d-m-Y", $lastDayUTS);
```

Answer (score 4):

How about :

```
date('1-m-Y',strtotime('this month'));
```