# how to get the date of the first day of the month in php

Tags: php, date

I am trying to get the date of the first of the month in PHP.

I found this page http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php where it seems you can do 'first day of...' but I don't see how you specify this month.

I also found [The first day of the current month in php using date_modify as DateTime object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094797/the-first-day-of-the-current-month-in-php-using-date-modify-as-datetime-object) and in the second answer I see you can do

```
date('Y-m-01');
```

The latter looks simple, but I don't understand how it specifies the current month. If someone can explain this to me, and also explain the difference in the two methods, that would be a big help!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: The default for the second parameter for [date](http://www.php.net/date) is the current date. For if formats the date with year and month of the current time then hard codes a 01 for the day

Comment: first day is always `1` its not like end day of the month which can be `30,31` and sometimes `28,29`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is my explaination, the php `date()` function actually has two inputs but one is optional. The first is the returned format, the second is the time you are converting to a string formatted date. If the second input isn't set it assumes you mean now, so all of these are the same:

```
date('Y-m-d');
date('Y-m-d',time());
date('Y-m-d',strtotime('now'));
```

So when you put in `date('Y-m-01')` it is pulling the year and month of now but you aren't making the day dynamic, you are forcing it to 01. So in reality here is what you are doing:

```
$date = date('Y-m') . '-01';
```

And of course this is server-side so it is based off of the server's clock.

Answer (score 3):

```
$date = new DateTime('first day of this month');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```