# php date output in yy instead of yyyy

Tags: php

I have very little knowledge of PHP.

I am trying to display or pass the 1st day of month in dd/mm/yyyy format but the result is dd/mm/yy.

My PHP query is

```
<? php
$month='Aug'
$year='2015'

$c=pdgwoconnect(); 
$sqlmy="SELECT TO_DATE("$month/$year","MM/YYYY")FRMDT, TO_DATE("$nextm/$year","MM/YYYY")TODT FROM DUAL";
$resultmy = OCIParse($c, $sqlmy);
OCIExecute($resultmy);

while ($row = oci_fetch_array($resultmy, OCI_ASSOC)) {
    $frmdt= $row["FRMDT"];
    $todt= $row["TODT"];
    echo $frmdt;
    echo "</br>";
    echo $todt;
}
?>
```

Result is 01-AUG-15 and 01-SEP-15

I want this in format 01-08-2015 or 01-AUG-2015 like this.

Comment: You would be better of by taking the raw timestamp and manipulating it in PHP with the DateTime object instead.

Comment: Cant you do this with PHP alone? [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094797/the-first-day-of-the-current-month-in-php-using-date-modify-as-datetime-object)

Comment: Hmm, it looks like you're trying to use Oracle to format the date instead of PHP's built-in functions.  This isn't going to work very well.  Skip all the database stuff and use something like this instead: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Also replace `<? php` with `<?php`

Answer (score 1):

First of all: **Why would you need to select a date from DB?**

The timezone set on your database engine / database connection *can be different* than the one you want, and it consumes resources (time mostly). So using DB for getting just the date and time seems to be *unnecessary, unadvised an also unefficient*.

Unless you have a very strict reason for that, I would recommend using PHP to retrieve the date you need, and here's how you can do it:

```
<?php
   // your input data as posted
   $month='Aug';
   $year='2015';
   $day = '01'; // since you need a first day of the month

   //create proper timezone that you need - I chose "Europe/London"
   $timeZoneString = 'Europe/London';
   $timeZone = new DateTimeZone($timeZoneString);

   //date string has to match format given in DateTime::createFromFormat()
   $dateString = "{$year}-{$month}-{$day}";
   $dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-M-d', $dateString, $timeZone);

   //you could see here what DateTime object looks like
   //var_dump($dateTime);

   //print the current date - the 1st Aug 2015 in deisred format
   echo $dateTime->format("d/m/Y"); // prints "01/08/2015"

   //create proper datetime interval
   $dateIntervalString = 'P1M'; // +1 month
   $dateInterval = new DateInterval($dateIntervalString);

   //add datetime interval to your date
   $dateTime->add($dateInterval);

   //print the date as you like, e.g. "dd/mm/yyyy"
   echo $dateTime->format("d/m/Y"); // prints "01/09/2015"
```

I checked this code and it works, and it has following advantages over your approach:

- it doesn't connect to DB (time and resource consuming)
- it is timezone-flexible (see [valid timezones list](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php))
- you can change the resulting format any time you want

BTW: I strongly recommend reading [this post on SO regarding date, time databases related best practises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-time-zone-best-practices).

Answer (score 0):

you can use
 if you want year like 2015 than use 'Y' in date formate

```
<?php
 $date = date('d-m-Y');
echo $date
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use php function `strtotime`

```
<?php
    echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime("$todt")); 
?>
```

Try this hope it will works