# How to print current month in Mysql DateTime format in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

how would I go about echo'ing the first and last day of the current month? I assume I would use mktime() but I am slightly confused by it.

For example the current month is June so I am looking for a way to echo:

```
2016-06-01 00:00:00
```

And

```
2016-06-30 00:00:00
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094797/the-first-day-of-the-current-month-in-php-using-date-modify-as-datetime-object

Comment: Why would  you use mktime? Both DateTime and strtotime() can give you the first day of this month, and from that it's easy to get the last day of the month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) for this.

```
<?php

    $start_date_month = new DateTime("first day of last month");
    $end_date_month = new DateTime("last day of last month");

    echo $start_date_month->format('Y-m-d'); 
    echo $end_date_month->format('Y-m-d');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method:

```
select date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 - day(curdate()) day) as month_start,
       date_sub(date_add(curdate(), interval 1 month), interval - day(curdate()) day) as month_end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ADDDATE(LAST_DAY(SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)),1) first, 
       LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) last
```

Comment: Could you maybe explain a bit what you code does, and how it works ? That would make it more helpful to future visitors.